# Apache CXF send custom headers with mustunderstand=true

Tags: apache, soap, wsdl, cxf

is there a possibility to send custom headers via CXF with the attribute mustunderstand=true?

I nowhere could find information about that topic.

Kind regards
Ali

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution.

Our approach is WSDL first. We generated our artifacts via wsdl2java with -exsh=true, which provides the possibility to set the header data via the generated API. By setting the header data via the generated API there is no way to set the "mustunderstand" flag.

We now generated the artifacts without "exsh=true" and set header via

```
ctx.put( Header.HEADER_LIST, headersList);
```

to the RequestContet.

Note: the headersList is a list containing

```
org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.SoapHeader
```

objects where you can set the "mustunderstand" flag.

Cheers,
Ali